# custom constraint in mvc3 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a custom route in asp.net MVC3 application and I want to create a route constraint which will check if the url has integer as second part of the parameter. If so, I need to redirect to different action.

product/12
product/12-2-1990

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it.

```
    ''# MapRoute allows for a dynamic product ID
    routes.MapRoute("Products", "product/{id}",
                             New With {.controller = "product",
                                       .action = "index"},
                             New With {.id = "[0-9]+") ''# this forces the ID to only be a number.
```

Then you will create your redirect logic separately. I would recommend using an ActionFilter to do your redirect work. You write it once and it can be implemented all over.

Comment: I need to do it using IRouterConstraint. What I was thiking is to create a constraint that checks if second path is number then redirect to one action otherwise return to second action method

Comment: Why not capture both in a Route and then use an ActionFilter to decide on the redirect?

Comment: how can I capture both in Rote ?

Comment: You can either create two routes that have the same controller and action destination (the easy way), or create a complex constraint regex to handle both in one (a little more challenging). Then you attach your ActionFilter to the `index` action of the `product` controller